# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'timesheet_id' InLineFormSets

Tags: django, attributes, foreign-keys, django-queryset

I'm trying to display existing entries for particular criteria on my webpage using an inlineformset. Here are the lines in my view

```
TimeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TimeSheet, Time, form=TimeForm, extra=1)
person_timesheets = Time.objects.filter(timesheet_id=timesheet)
print person_timesheets.count()
time_formset = TimeFormSet(instance=person_timesheets)
```

I don't understand why this is causing

> 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'timesheet_id'

print person_timesheets.count() returns a number to my console no problem... I must be using instance wrong here.

Here are my models

```
class Time(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    timesheet_id = models.ForeignKey(TimeSheet, null=True, related_name="time_set")
    def __unicode__ (self):
        return self.description

class TimeSheet(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length= 50, default="Open", choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
```

When I save my Time in my view I set the timesheet_id field with the Django assigned id of the related TimeSheet (not sure if this is a messy way to do this...).

```
def week(request, timesheet_id):
    # navigated from previous timesheet view
    timesheet = TimeSheet.objects.get(pk=timesheet_id)

    TimeFormSet = inlineformset_factory(TimeSheet, Time, form=TimeForm, extra=1)
    person_timesheets = Time.objects.filter(timesheet_id=timesheet)
    print person_timesheets.count()
    time_formset = TimeFormSet(instance=person_timesheets)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        time_formset = TimeFormSet(request.POST)
        #check validity first
        if time_formset.is_valid():
            for form in time_formset:
                form.timesheet_id = timesheet
                form.save()

    context = {
        "timesheet": timesheet,
        "time_formset": time_formset,
    }    
    return render(request, 'tande/week.html', context)
```

EDIT: Traceback

```
Internal Server Error: /tande/1/timesheet/week/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/ruthyoung/Documents/code/prodman/tande/views.py", line 344, in week
    time_formset = TimeFormSet(instance=person_timesheets.timesheet_id)
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'timesheet_id'
```

Help!?

Comment: Could you post the whole traceback please and not just the `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'timesheet_id'` part?

Comment: @nik_m Traceback added :)

Comment: You're passing a `QuerySet` instead of an `instance`. You must first get a single `TimeSheet` object and then *feed* `TimeFormSet` with that object (not a queryset). Then you may create a formset that allows you to edit `Time`s belonging to a particular `TimeSheet`.

Comment: Would you mind show the `views` ?

Comment: @nik_m I've put the view up. Okay so I can only pass one object to it. But then how do I show all existing objects related to it? rather than just one? I'm trying to display all forms with 'timesheet_id=timesheet'

Comment: Did any of the below answers helped you to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's not a good practice to name your related fields as `related_name_id`. Just `related_name`. That's because when, in the future, you want to get the `id` of the related field it's more readable to write it this way `filter(related_name__id=4)` instead of `filter(related_name_id__id=4)`.
2. You're passing a `Time QuerySet` instead of a `TimeSheet` instance inside the `TimeFormSet` formset factory. Change to `time_formset = TimeFormSet(instance=timesheet)`.
3. If you want to show all existing objects related to it, then just `time_formset = TimeFormSet(instance=timesheet, queryset=person_timesheets)`

Answer (score 0):

Remember that when you use `Time.objects.filter(timesheet_id=timesheet)` you are getting a QuerySet(a list of instances from the model, in this case `Time` model)

When you do: `instance=person_timesheets` are asigning to instance the full queryset (all instances returned by the query) not an specific instance, and for this reason throws the error `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'timesheet_id'`

Try with:

```
person_timesheets = Time.objects.get(id=timesheet_id)
time_formset = TimeFormSet(instance=person_timesheets)
```